# UWP - Splitview define relative value to OpenPaneLength

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app, uwp, splitview

I'm using the new `SplitView` control to create a hamburger menu in my `UWP` app.
My question is if I can define a relative or percentage value to its `OpenPaneLength` property? I want to achieve that the width of the `SplitView`'s `Pane` is for example 80% of the device's width.

Thank you!

This is the `XAML` code of the `SplitView`

```
<SplitView x:Name="ShellSplitView"
           DisplayMode="Overlay"
           IsPaneOpen="False"
           OpenPaneLength="300">
    <SplitView.Pane>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RadioButton x:Name="SettingsButton"
                         Grid.Row="1"
                         Content="Settings"
                         Checked="OnSettingsButtonChecked" />
        </Grid>
    </SplitView.Pane>
    <SplitView.Content>...</SplitView.Content>
</SplitView>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to monitor whenever the `IsPaneOpen` flag is set to `true`, calculate the `OpenPaneLength` based on its parent container's `ActualWidth`.

```
this.SplitView.RegisterPropertyChangedCallback(SplitView.IsPaneOpenProperty, IsPaneOpenPropertyChanged);


private void IsPaneOpenPropertyChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyProperty dp)
{
    if (this.SplitView.IsPaneOpen)
    {
        this.SplitView.OpenPaneLength = this.LayoutRoot.ActualWidth * .8;
    }
}
```

Comment: Also, subscribe to resize of parent control... Which may be resized by splitview itself (though, I'm not sure), so add handler to that too... Why they didn't used just relative notation, like "0.5*"?